# Unable to take full String input from console

Tags: java, arrays, string, input, console

```
public class PairsWithSumK 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Write your code here
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int test= sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<test;i++)
        {
            int num= sc.nextInt();
            int sum= sc.nextInt();
            String a;
            a = sc.next();
            String [] array= a.split(" ");
            int count=0;
            for(int j=0;j<num;j++)
             {
                int x=0;
                x=sum-Integer.parseInt(array[j]);
                String xs =String.valueOf(x);
                if(Arrays.asList(array).contains(xs))
                {
                    int index=Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(xs);
                    array[index]=array[j]="-1";
                    count++;

                }
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
}
```

I've been trying to take console input in java but instead of taking the whole line and then converting it into a string array, the code is only taking the 1st character. For eg: input-"1 2 3 4 5 6", the string "a" will only take 1. Being a new to coding, I am stuck at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next() method of the scanner only takes the string to the next delimiter (default case a whitespace). So in your case each call auf sc.next() would read in one of your number (first 1, then 2, etc.).

So in your code you would not read them in as string and split that, but just fill each index of the array seperatly with sc.next().

(you can use sc.hasNext() to see if you have added the whole input).

Answer (score 0):

By default `Scanner` us using as delimiter *one or more white-spaces* and `next()` will try to read and return token until next delimiter. So for instance if your input would be

```
1 2 foo bar
```

then code such as this will return

```
nextInt(); // 1
nextInt(); // 2
next();    // foo
next();    // bar
```

Notice that first `next()` didn't return `foo bar` but only `foo` because there was delimiter after it, so there is no space to split on. If you would like to read rest of line you would need to use `nextLine()`

But be careful with that method since if your input would be `1\nfoo` and you will call `nextInt` and `nextLine` you will get `1` and `""` (empty String) as result, because next line tries to read content until next line separator, or until end of data. So in case of `1\nfoo` after `nextInt()` cursor will be set after `1` like `1|\nfoo` so between its current position and next line separator (`\n`) is only empty string.